# Remove all the colons in filenames on a directory

Tags: python

My problem is that when I am building a list of files from a network share to subsequently do stuff to, a number of the files then fail, (I found this when I stuck the print(file) statement in.  This is because I have found via process of trial and error that the files on the share have a colon : in them.

PROBLEM:  I want to do a recursive bulk rename of all the files in the share where I replace the special character : with say an underscore _ , but I don't know how to do this as : is a special character.

See below the code that errors, but the code itself looks fine. It's the data that is causing it to error.  It runs fine until it encounters a file which has a colon in the name.

```
def __init__(self):
    """Initialise the class"""
    self.settings = Settings()

def run_merge(self):
    subfolders, files = self.get_worklist(self.settings.mypath)
    for x in range(len(files)):
        file = files[x]
        print(file)

def get_worklist(self, path):
    containers, targets = BuildList.worklist(self.settings.mypath, [".jpg"])
    return containers, targets
```

I tried forcing a different encoding, (see below), which I think worked better, but then all the files ended up with loads of extra \ and // in them which would then be a nightmare to work out what to strip when I want to operate on the files later.

```
    for x in range(len(files)):
        #file = files[x].encode('utf8')
        file = files[x]
        print(file)
```

so I would rather fix the data quality issue at the source and simply strip all the colons out and replace with underscores, hence my question

Comment: Nothing about ":" is special to Python. If you are on an OS where this character has special meanings, what works will depend on which OS and what file names it allows. If you are on Windows, what can be done is really limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on which OS you're working in, there are various solutions to this issue. But to make something that's OS independent I'll use python 3's pathlib module from the stdlib.

```py
from pathlib import Path


def main():
    cwd_path = Path(".")
    directories = []
    files = []

    # Handle initially populating the directories inside current
    # working directory.
    for item in cwd_path.iterdir():
        if item.is_dir():
            directories.append(item)
        else:
            files.append(item)

    # Process all directories, and add any sub-directories to the queue
    # to be processed. This uses a BFS (Breadth First Search) approach.
    while len(directories) > 0:
        new_directory: Path = directories.pop(0)

        for sub_item in new_directory.iterdir():
            if sub_item.is_dir():
                directories.append(sub_item)
            else:
                files.append(sub_item)

    # Locate all files containing : in their name and replace them
    # with an otherwise identical filename but with _ instead.
    file: Path
    for file in files:
        file_name = file.name

        if ":" in file_name:
            new_name = file_name.replace(":", "_")
            new_path = f"{file.parent}/{new_name}"
            file.replace(new_path)
            print(f"Wrote {new_path}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This will need to be run inside the top most directory of the file share containing the files with the problematic colons, or alternatively, update the `cwd_path` variable to be an absolute path to the directory to start scanning from.

Lastly, it should be noted that file names containing `:` are not valid on Windows, so if you're trying to access these files by running an application on windows... then that's not going to go well. You'll need to use some variant of linux distro and run the above code on the directory to resolve the problem.

Comment: Thanks so much!   Yes I wonder how the files ended up with a ":" in the first place.

I am going to go through this in detail and really understand it.   Appreciate your help "root" and I'll help someone else today in return.

Comment: hi "root".   absolutely bizarre... python on windows will find the bad filenames, but cannot do anything with them.  I put Python on my Synology NAS box and SSH'ed in and it will not find the bad files.  e.g. if I say 
if "Mavericks:" in file_name it will find
Mavericks: Expeditionary Force Book 3.mp3
if I say only if ":" in file_name it doesn't find anything to rename.

Comment: update.. I found that the so-called colons are not actually colons... I did some digging and they are ascii code 42889.  so now I'm trying to do a change to the if statement but do a reverse search for ascii code 42889 to somehow rename it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help.. here's the code in the end that seems to work.

```
from pathlib import Path
import re

def main():
    #cwd_path = Path(r"\\rex\Audiobooks")
    cwd_path = Path(r"t:\downloads")
    directories = []
    files = []
    code = 42889 #the ascii code for the dreaded colon which isn't a colon

    # Handle initially populating the directories inside current
    # working directory.
    for item in cwd_path.iterdir():
        if item.is_dir():
            directories.append(item)
        else:
            files.append(item)
    
    
    # Process all directories, and add any sub-directories to the queue
    # to be processed. This uses a BFS (Breadth First Search) approach.
    while len(directories) > 0:
        new_directory: Path = directories.pop(0)
        
        for sub_item in new_directory.iterdir():
            if sub_item.is_dir():
                directories.append(sub_item)
            else:
                files.append(sub_item)
    
    # Locate all files containing : in their name and replace them
    # with an otherwise identical filename but with _ instead.

    file: Path
    for file in files:
        file_name = file.name
        """this next section can be uncommented to find out what
        the code is that is causing errors"""
        #test = [ord(l) for l in file_name]
        #print(test)
        #print(f"All files", {file_name.encode('utf8')}, file_name.isascii())
        """check for dodgy characters"""
        validate = file_name.isascii()
        if validate == False:
            print(f"found a file to be renamed", {file_name.encode('utf8')})
            test = [ord(l) for l in file_name]
            print(test)

        if not file_name.isascii():
            print(f"found a file to be renamed", {file_name.encode('utf8')})
            
            #fix the supposed colon"
            if chr(code) in file_name:
                new_name = file_name.replace(chr(code), "_")
                new_path = f"{file.parent}/{new_name}"
                #file.replace(new_path)
                #print(f"Wrote {new_path}")

            #strip fix the rest of the non ascii characters
            new_name = re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7f]',r'', file_name)
            new_path = f"{file.parent}/{new_name}"
            file.replace(new_path)
            print(f"Wrote {new_path}")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```